# SortedSet.Remove() does not remove anything

Tags: c#, graph, dijkstra, sortedset

I am currently implementing Dijkstra's algorithm and I am using the C# SortedSet as a priority queue.
However, in order to keep track of what vertices I have already visited, I want to remove the first item from the priority queue.

Here is my code:

```
static int shortestPath(int start, int target)
    {
        SortedSet<int> PQ = new SortedSet<int>(new compareByVertEstimate());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (i == start - 1)
                vertices[i].estimate = 0;
            else
                vertices[i].estimate = int.MaxValue;

            PQ.Add(i);
        }

        int noOfVisited = 0;
        while (noOfVisited < n)
        {
            int u = PQ.First();
            noOfVisited++;

            foreach (Edge e in vertices[u].neighbours)
            {
                if (vertices[e.target.Item1].estimate > vertices[u].estimate + e.length)
                {
                    vertices[e.target.Item1].estimate = vertices[u].estimate + e.length;
                }
            }

            PQ.Remove(u);
        }
        return vertices[target - 1].estimate;
    }
```

And this is the comparer:

```
public class compareByVertEstimate : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare(int a, int b)
    {

        if (Program.vertices[a].estimate >= Program.vertices[b].estimate) return 1;
        else return -1;
    }
}
```

My priority queue does not explicitly hold vertices, instead I have an array of vertices and the priority queue holds the indices.
So the priority queue is sorted based on the 'estimate' integer that each vertex holds.

Now my problem is, I can easily retrieve the first element from the SortedSet using .First(), or .Min, but when I try to remove that element with .Remove(), the method returns false, and nothing gets removed. The SortedSet remains unchanged.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
I changed the Comparer to this:

```
public class compareByVertEstimate : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare(int a, int b)
    {

        if (Program.vertices[a].estimate == Program.vertices[b].estimate) return 0;
        else if (Program.vertices[a].estimate >= Program.vertices[b].estimate) return 1;
        else return -1;
    }
}
```

But now the priority queue doesn't contain all the right elements anymore.
(Note, the priority queue will contain pointers to vertices that have the same estimate value)

Comment: While your immediate question has been answered, I think it's important to point out that you appear to be changing the estimate of vertices after they've been added to your `SortedSet`. That's not going to work. `SortedSet` won't re-sort any items, and it will break badly if the items are no longer sorted.

Comment: I noticed that too, I have changed my code so that every time I discover a new vertex, it gets added to the SortedSet, instead of adding them all beforehand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your compare function *never* compares two elements as *equal* (`return 0;`).

Your collection will not be able to remove an element that is not equal to any element it holds.

Example:

```
public class compareByVertEstimate : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare(int a, int b)
    {

        if (a == b) return 0;

        if (Program.vertices[a].estimate >= Program.vertices[b].estimate) return 1;

        return -1;
    }
}
```

@hvd is correct of course, while the above version works, it's quite broken. A better comparer might be:

```
public class compareByVertEstimate : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare(int a, int b)
    {
        var ae = Program.vertices[a].estimate;
        var be = Program.vertices[b].estimate; 

        var result = ae.CompareTo(be);

        if (result == 0) return a.CompareTo(b);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a line to check for equality, but will the priority queue still function? There are vertices that have the same estimate value, and I still want them added to the priority queue.

Comment: @vanLeemhuyzen You don't need to compare estimates, you only need to make sure that an index compares as *equal* to the very same index.

Comment: A comparer where `Compare(a, b)` can return `1` while `Compare(b, a)` can also return `1` at the same time is horribly broken and won't work with the standard classes. If you check the estimates at all, of course you need more than `==`.

Comment: Note: the change `==` to `>=` is insufficient. If `a != b`, but `vertices[a].estimate == vertices[b].estimate`, you still get the situation where `Compare(a, b)` and `Compare(b, a)` both return `1`.

Comment: @hvd The == was just a typo I noticed. The new comparer should work fine. Sort order between estimates of the same value now depend on index value, but the only thing that really counts is that they don't compare as equal.

Comment: I wrote a simple in-line use case, Remove worked okay. But in a more complex case, couldn't get it working. After an hour gave up and spent 5 minutes switching to a List that I sort as needed. Works great.